# JQuery FadeIn on Window Load not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have recently begun learning JavaScript/Jquery and the first thing I thought I would do in order to practise what I have learnt is making a piece of text fadeIn() on the load/refresh of the website. For some reason, what I have made does not work and I cannot figure out why. I have reconciled all the JQuery courses I have been through and it should work (-Yes the script is linked-)

Please could someone help me! Thank You!

HTML:

```
 <div class="underTitle" id="underTitle">
    <a href="index.html" class="fadeInLoad"><h2>Welcome to my Homepage</h2></a>
    <img src="images/faviconp.png" width="50" height="50" alt="Lighting Bolt Logo" id="logovAlign">
 </div>
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('window').on('load', () => {
        $('.fadeInLoad').fadeIn();
    });

});
```

JavaScript/JQuery Link:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is an object not string .. try `$(window).on(...`

Also make sure the `<a>` is hidden to begin with. Can't fade in something that is already visible

Comment: Thanks for that it worked! But my next question would be, how would I get it to slideDown() whilst fading in simultaneously?